# How Do I Know When to Update My Local git Tools on My Windows Development Machine?

Tags: windows, git, github-for-windows

A nube to git for sure, and working on windows platform at my employer (starting to use linux/mac more at home)...

I like to keep my tools current, so I don't run into bugs and/or miss out on new features (when they're stable).

Is there a standard/obvious/customary way to know when it's time to get the latest version of the git tools?

PS: I got started by using the github for windows downloads in case that matters.

EDIT: Any answers for a non-github for windows scenario appreciated.

Comment: GitHub for Windows automatically updates itself. If you continue to use that tool you should be good to go.

Comment: Previous comment is the best, but another way to go is build the git tools for yourself.  Build from master and you will always have the latest stable code.  This is not recommended if you're not reasonably familiar with building open source projects.  I pull every day and build whenever master updates.